# hl-sexp-mode fails to load on start-up

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have a problem with my .emacs file: everything loads fine, but one minor mode does not load.

Here is the code:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") 1)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(load "macros")
(load-theme 'zenburn 1)

(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
(savehist-mode 1)
(windmove-default-keybindings 'meta)
(electric-indent-mode -1)
(hl-sexp-mode 1)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

When emacs opens, **hl-sexp-mode** is disabled, but when I run eval-buffer on the .emacs file, the mode is activated.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the global hl-sexp-mode by replacing `(hl-sexp-mode)` with `(global-hl-sexp-mode)` to your init file. `hl-sexp-mode` enables the mode locally i.e. for the buffer from which it is called, I am not sure what is the current buffer is when Emacs is initializing.

Comment: This would also explain why the OP finds it works after running `eval-buffer` on the init file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it works when you use eval-buffer; there doesn't seem to be a hl-sexp-mode function defined (at least in the version on github).  Instead of (hl-sexp-mode 1), try (highlight-sexp-mode 1) in its place.

Comment: It returns "Symbol's function definition is void: highlight-sexp-mode".

Comment: @Dan, the `hl-sexp-mode` is created by the `define-minor-mode` macro, do `C-h f` hl-sexp-mode `RET`